# Transform not working when I'm clicking on the ul li menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hover effect on the list items. When I should hover on the menu items, the circle should move inwards. But, in my case everything is moving inwards.

My code:

```css
.career li{
  list-style-image:url('../images/arrow-right.png');
  margin-left: -15px;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #606b72;
  line-height:43px;
}


.career li:hover{
  
    transform: translate(5px,0px) rotate(-0deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="career">
  <li><a>Frontend Developer</a></li>
  <li><a>Kubernetes/Docker Expert</a> </li>
  <li><a>DevOps Engineer</a></li>
  <li><a>Software Quality Assurance Engineer</a></li>
  <li><a>Frontend developer</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can someone please help me to fix this issue. The circle should move inward. Thank You.

Comment: Set list-style to none, do your own bullets with e.g. `::before` and animate those

Comment: But how. Will you help me a little.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot separately animate default list bullets.
I removed default bullets with `list-style: none` and added a `::before` pseudo-element to your list items containing a bullet character, which can be animated separately for it is actually a separate (pseudo) element.

```css
.career li{
  list-style-image:url('../images/arrow-right.png');
  margin-left: -15px;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #606b72;
  line-height:43px;
  list-style:none;
}
.career li::before {
    content: '•';
    margin-right: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}


.career li:hover::before{
  
    transform: translate(5px,0px) rotate(-0deg);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="career">
  <li><a>Frontend Developer</a></li>
  <li><a>Kubernetes/Docker Expert</a> </li>
  <li><a>DevOps Engineer</a></li>
  <li><a>Software Quality Assurance Engineer</a></li>
  <li><a>Frontend developer</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.career li {
    font-size:1.4em;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    list-style: none;
}
.career li::before {
   content: ".";
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
}
.career li:hover::before {
   transform: translate(5px,0px) rotate(-0deg);
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
   transition: -webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 337ms ease-in-out,-webkit-transform 337ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<ul class="career">
  <li><a>Frontend Developer</a></li>
  <li><a>Kubernetes/Docker Expert</a> </li>
  <li><a>DevOps Engineer</a></li>
  <li><a>Software Quality Assurance Engineer</a></li>
  <li><a>Frontend developer</a></li>
</ul>
```